# Ubuntu completely hangs in VMware player on text scolling in terminal

Tags: 22.04, vmware, 23.10

I try to run Ubuntu (22.04, 23.10, clear setup) in VMware player. The system completely hangs when I do basic text manipulation in nano.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open terminal
2. open nano
3. type few symbols
4. hold "arrow down"

The system completely hangs. Please advice where to find any logs or what to change in settings.

Comment: I question "system hang". Is `nano` simply adding new lines?

Comment: The interesting thing is the issue happens only with the arrow down button. With the arrow left/right it doesn't reproduce. If I hold it for ~5 sec and then press the arrow left, the cursor moves left in a few seconds. If hold more, the system hangs. Also reproducible in terminal without nano.

It looks like some queue overflow, but I don't know whether Ubuntu has such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer:

I needed to disable Memory Integrity.

Windows Security -> Device Security -> Core Isolation details